# Creating a new vector using a for loop with an if condition

Tags: r, apply, mapply

I am facing an issue with for loops in R. I need to create a new vector if a certain condition applies to a data element. However, I only want R to loop through the first 49 columns of my data set. This is the code I have so far but R is returning multiple error messages.

```
meanedu = c()
count= 0
sum = 0
 ###HV105.01:HV105.49 are the columns for which I want the for loop to run###
for i in ncol(HV105.01:HV105.49) i++) } 
  ###burkina cut is the name of the dataset. I want the for loop to run for all rows###
     for (j in nrow(burkinacut) j++) { 
##defining a new variable age which is the position [1,1] in my dataset### 
         age = burkinacut[i,j]
         if (age >= 25) {
##if age>=25 create a new vector adult edu which is the value 49 spaces to the right from the current data element##
            adultedu= (i, j+49)
            sum = sum + adultedu ###sum this vector###
            count= count++
         }
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to make this code run. I tried to put in explanations to explain what I was hoping to do. From research I have done, the apply, lapply, or mapply functions may be best to use but I do not understand how to use them in this context.

Comment: first off, your syntax for the `for` loop is off. Try something like `for (i in 1:49){do something}`

Comment: A nice perk of R being an interpreted language is that you can run little pieces of code to see if the syntax is valid. For example, here you could run just `HV105.01:HV105.49` and the error will tell you it's not a valid way to get a sequence of columns. You can test if periods work for accessing columns by trying `HV105.01` and when that doesn't work you can maybe remember to use `[` instead. Similarly, `2++` doesn't work, so `i++` won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different approach to your problem.

First, let's generate a sample data set:

```
set.seed(2015) # make sure the example is reproducible

# create a sample data set
d <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(20:40,20,replace=T),nrow=4))
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
# 1 21 22 33 20 25
# 2 37 27 30 28 21
# 3 26 30 34 35 37
# 4 20 21 28 38 28
```

For simplicity, I will assume that you are interested in first four columns. Also, I will assume the data set doesn't have `NA` values.

You can create a boolean mask matrix of elements that satisfy the desired conditions:

```
bm <- (d >= 25 & col(d) <= 4)
#         V1    V2   V3    V4    V5
# [1,] FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [2,]  TRUE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [3,]  TRUE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Then, `bm` can be used to subset only the elements of interest:

```
d[bm]
#[1] 37 26 27 30 33 30 34 28 28 35 38
```

for which it will be trivial to calculate sum:

```
sum(d[bm])
# [1] 346
```

or number of elements:

```
length(d[bm])
# [1] 11
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. The only problem is (and using the above matrix as an example) Once I find out which elements satisfies the condition (in your case d>=25), I need find the data element that is 49 columns to the right. What I am trying to do is determine if a certain data element satisfies a condition and if it does, find the element that is 49 columns away. While I could do this by hand, my data set has 14,000 rows which I why I am doing this with R

Comment: You can do `bm <- (d >= 25 & (ncol(d) - col(d) < 49))`